# Runing a custom executable on PDF files stored in azure blob storage with azure web app front-end

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a web app built using ASP.NET 4.5/C# and is hosted in azure as a Web App. The site allows users to upload PDF files which are then stored in a azure blob container and can later be download via the website as needed. So far so good and everything was working fine.

We now have a new requirement which involves processing these files using the custom win32 executable and the website must know if the processing was successful or not. This exe has a setup file and must be installed on the target machine before it can be used.

I have been scratching my head over how to architect this feature. I have come across many articles which tell a Worker Role is needed, or a VM is needed. But all articles seem to a very abstract.

Given that the installer for the executable requires manual intervention, I am thinking a Azure VM is the way to go. But how will the web app communicate to this. How do I notify the web app with the result of the process?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install such software in an Azure Web App, since web apps are sandboxed. As such, you won't be able to run that setup `exe`.

For such processing, you'd need to run that part of your app in a Virtual Machine or web/worker role.

Answer (score 0):

> But how will the web app communicate to this. How do I notify the web app with the result of the process?

[Azure Queue storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues) could meet your requirement. It can provide cloud messaging between application components. Your VM could write the process result to a queue and your web app could read the process result from the same queue.

To add a new message to a queue, you could reference following code.

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the queue client.
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

// Retrieve a reference to a queue.
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");

// Create the queue if it doesn't already exist.
queue.CreateIfNotExists();

// Create a message and add it to the queue.
CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage("Hello, World");
queue.AddMessage(message);
```

In Your Web App, you could create a [QueueTrigger WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to), the job will be executed immediately if any new message has been added to the queue.

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("myqueue")] string processResult, TextWriter log)
{
   //You can get the processResult and do anything needed here
}
```